# How to solve x'+x=delta(x) with Laplace transform.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I'm solving the following ODE:
$$x'+x=\delta(t)\tag{1}$$
where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function.
By Laplace transform, I get
$$sX(s)-x(0)+X(s)=1.$$
Hence,
$$X(s)=\frac{x(0)+1}{s+1}\tag{2}$$
Now implement the inverse transform:
$$x(t)=[x(0)+1]\exp(-t)\tag{3}$$
However, this is obviously not correct because when I let $t=0$ in formula (3), I get $x(0)=x(0)+1$
I want to know where I made a mistake, and how to solve it correctly by Laplace Transform.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no $x(0)$ at the singularity, the result you get is $x(t)=u(t)e^{-t}$.

Comment: But how to obtain $u(t)$ instead of $x(0)+1$? Thank you! @LutzLehmann

Comment: The delta on the right produces a jump in the solution, so $x(0^-)=x_0$ and $x(0^+)=x_0+1$. In that understanding also your result is not wrong if you interpret it correctly as $x(0^+)=x(0^-)+1$.

Comment: So the solution should be $x(t)=\begin{cases}x_0,&t<0\\(x_0+1)\exp(-t),&t>0\end{cases}$. Is this correct?@LutzLehmann

Comment: No, it is $x_0e^{-t}$ for $t<0$. On both segments outside $t=0$ you still get a solution of the homogeneous equation.

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me a lot! @LutzLehmann

Comment: Isn't the correct ODE: $x'(t)+x(t)=\delta (\color{red}{t})$

Comment: It has been corrected now. @gpmath